# Django: Cannot resolve keyword into field. Choices are:

Tags: python, django

I know there quite a few posts here with a very similar problem but none of them helped me.

I'm getting this error when I try to access the specialization from the admin panel. It started happening right after I added sub_specialization in doctor entity and made specialization a foreign key.

Traceback:

```
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1306.                 self)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  74.         self.root_queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
File "/Users/harisaghadi/code/meddy Production App/m1/admin.py" in get_queryset
  50.         return qs.annotate(doctor_count=Count('doctor')).order_by('-doctor_count')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in annotate
  717.                 is_summary=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_aggregate
  988.                 field_list, opts, self.get_initial_alias())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in setup_joins
  1363.             names, opts, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1283.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/m1/specialization/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'doctor' into field. Choices are: doctor_specialization, doctor_subSpecialization, id, meta, name, page_name
```

here is the admin.py

```
    class SpecializationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        formfield_overrides = {
            models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'200'})},
            models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':40})},

        }

        list_display = ['name','doctor_count_display', 'meta', 'page_name']

        def get_queryset(self, request):
            qs = super(SpecializationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
            return qs.annotate(doctor_count=Count('doctor')).order_by('-doctor_count')

        def doctor_count_display(self, obj):
            return obj.doctor_count
        doctor_count_display.short_description = 'Number of doctors'
        doctor_count_display.admin_order_field = 'doctor_count'

admin.site.register(Specialization, SpecializationAdmin)
```

Models.py

```
class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    meta = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank = True, null = True)
    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization, related_name = "doctor_specialization")
    sub_specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization, related_name = "doctor_subSpecialization", null = True, blank = True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
```

Comment: You don't have a `doctor` field anymore; since you gave it a custom `related_name`; so this `qs.annotate(doctor_count=Count('doctor'))` is not working.

Comment: thanks @BurhanKhalid! You can add it as an answer and I can tick market it.

Comment: As @BurhanKhalid said change this line to qs.annotate(doctor_count=Count('doctor_specialization')).order_by('-doctor_count')

Comment: And a little tip for future: style guide says that you should not use spaces around `=` in model field definitions (and functions, etc.): `ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True)`